# How to get Apple Music to auto-generate custom playlists? Spotify-like

Tags: music, siri, apple-music, playlist, homepod

I've been a Spotify user for a while and appreciate that based on a genre, an artist, or even a single song, it can automatically create a playlist with that genre or with similar artists/songs that go well together.

Is there a way I can replicate that with Apple Music?

We recently got a Home Pod, so we got the free trial for 6 months of Apple Music. But whenever I ask Siri for something like, "90s rock" then it plays an album that has 90s rock in the title (always telling me "by various artists") – but it doesn't create it's own playlist and also doesn't seem to learn our prefs.

Comment: It may depend on the actual command, see https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/s/iPNdSgHJuk and similar pages.

Answer (score 0):

[Use Siri to play music and podcasts (Apple)](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208279):

> "Hey Siri, play some 90's alternative music."

> Tip: Siri takes the work out of choosing what to play next. Just ask Siri to play a song, and similar songs will play automatically.